# Arrays in Swift - How to add images

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, image

I am making an application that keeps score from 1 to 20 and then displays an image if the score is >= 21. However I don't know how to go about this, I have a label that displays the users score in integers. Is there a way that I can add an image to the array after 20? Or is there a way to add a string when score >= 21 that says "Bullseye" either the string or image. I just dont know the best way to do this any help?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//Below are all of the labels at the top of AZG
@IBOutlet weak var user1name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var user2name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_currentPlayer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var user1score: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var user2score: UILabel!



//Below are all the declared variables
var usernames = ["Big Meat ", "J Hooks "]
var currentPlayer = 0
var scores = [0,0]
var count = 0
var sdCount = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   setupGame()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func newGame() {
    user1score.text = "\(count)"
    user2score.text = "\(count)"
    user1name.text = "\(usernames[0])"
    user2name.text = "\(usernames[1])"
    lbl_currentPlayer.text = usernames[currentPlayer]
    scores = [0,0]
}

func setupGame() {
    user1score.text = "\(count)"
    user2score.text = "\(count)"
    user1name.text = "\(usernames[0])"
    user2name.text = "\(usernames[1])"
    lbl_currentPlayer.text = usernames[currentPlayer]
}

func updateTurn() {
    lbl_currentPlayer.text = usernames[currentPlayer]
    user1score.text = "\(scores[0])"
    user2score.text = "\(scores[1])"
}

func attackTurnUpdate() {
    currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
}

func resetAttackTurn() {
    currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
}

func missedNextTurn() {
    currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
}

func suddenDeath() {
    sdCount = sdCount++
}

func takeStepBack() {
}

func bullseyeDisplay() {

}

@IBAction func hitSingle(sender: AnyObject) {
    scores[currentPlayer]++
    updateTurn()
}

@IBAction func nextTurn(sender: AnyObject) {
    currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
    updateTurn()
}
```

Comment: Try keeping an image view near the label.. Assign an image to that image view only if the score is >=21. Can you try that ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what the link with an array is?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the image to your view in interface builder (with an appropriate IBOutlet in your code) and set "Hidden" on it.

Then when you want to display the image, just change the value of hidden:

```
my image.hidden = false
```